# Problem with SSL Certificate when the .Net App calls itself in the docker container

Tags: .net, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I have a project that contains both my API with its controllers and everything else, as well as identityserver4 running under the same localhost. Everything works great when I'm not using docker, but as soon as I use docker I keep getting the following error when calling a secured API route :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:8001/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:8001/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I do understand that this's mainly an SSL certificate validation problem on docker's container side, because when I'm inside the container and I run a curl command to the lcoalhost :

```
curl https://localhost:8001
```

I get the following error :

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

But I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this issue. I did run these commands to generate a pfx and user secrets:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\dotnetproject.pfx -p 123456 -t
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
    
dotnet user-secrets init -p dotnetproject.csproj
dotnet user-secrets -p dotnetproject.csproj set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "123456"
```

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows :

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
      - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ 
        
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+"
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123456
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.aspnet/https/dotnetproject.pfx
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And here's the .net app dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I really don't knwo what I'm missing and what I can do to resolve this. Thanks for your help.